# Get city suggestions from the city, that user entered android

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

Can I get city suggestions from google maps after user entered the name so user can choose the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the autocomplete feature from Google Place API.

You can visit [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/training/autocomplete-android) about Adding Place Autocomplete to your Android App.

Or you can read [this tutorial](https://ddewaele.github.io/GoogleMapsV2WithActionBarSherlock/part5) about using Place Autocomplete in EditText field.